# How can I configure mail for Drupal 7 on an Ubuntu Raring EC2 node?

Tags: amazon-ec2, postfix, amazon-web-services, dovecot, drupal

I have installed apache2, php5, mysql5, php5-mysql and other supporting packages on an EC2 server, and when I started to install drupal7, it pulled in several packages including mail support, and presented me with a screen:

Package configuration

┌────────────────────────┤ Postfix Configuration ├────────────────────────┐
  │                                                                         │ 
  │ Please select the mail server configuration type that best meets your
  │ needs.
  │
  │  No configuration:
  │   Should be chosen to leave the current configuration unchanged.
  │  Internet site:
  │   Mail is sent and received directly using SMTP.
  │  Internet with smarthost:
  │   Mail is received directly using SMTP or by running a utility such
  │   as fetchmail. Outgoing mail is sent using a smarthost.
  │  Satellite system:
  │   All mail is sent to another machine, called a 'smarthost', for
  │ delivery.
  │  Local only:
  │
  │                                 
  │                                                                         │ 
  └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

What is/are the preferred way(s) to get mail working adequately for Drupal on an EC2 server running Ubuntu Raring? I searched and didn't find a recommendation.

--EDIT (clarification)--

The paste above is from Ubuntu Raring's aptitude program, which is requesting to know how to configure Postfix (and, perhaps, other programs pulled in). I am not asking how to configure Drupal once I have a working local SMTP server. I am asking how to configure postfix, pulled in by aptitude on an attempt to install drupal7, so that I **have** a working local SMTP server. This is for an EC2 instance, and I don't know what is appropriate in EC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't got a smart host to relay mail through then you will have to choose "internet site" this will let you send mail from Drupal, Drupal will then just SMTP connect to the local mail server to send mail.

Comment: Please see the clarification above; I am trying to configure Postfix to presumably **get** a local mail server.

Comment: @JonathanHayward Please re read my answer I know what your after its quite clear. When you choose "internet site" as suggested in my answer you will have a fully functional local mail server that Drupal can send email through.